# EmEditor Macro to Save Large Files from 0 to 100000

Tags: javascript, macros, emeditor

Trying to set up a macro for EmEditor to execute the following steps that I could otherwise do manually.

1. open file
2. view > large file controller
3. set To=1000
4. Click Apply
5. Click Save Opened Portion As...
6. Enter TestMacro and Save

I'm using: EmEditor Professional (64-bit) version 22.4.1. Windows 10 operating system.

I tried recording, that didnt seem to work.

Then I tried variations of this snippet suggested as answer but error provided was specificed file does not exist.

```
editor.WriteProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "DefaultBytesTo", 1000 );    // open to 1000 bytes
editor.RefreshCommonSettings();
editor.OpenFile( "D:\\Test\\Input.txt", 0, eeOpenDetectUnicode | eeOpenDetectUTF8 );
editor.WriteProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "DefaultBytesTo", 0 );       // open to unlimited
editor.RefreshCommonSettings();
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear All Bookmarks in This Document
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4588);  // Invert Bookmarks in This Document
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4590);  // Extract Bookmarked Lines in This Document to New File
document.Save( "D:\\Test\\TestMacro.txt" );
```

How is this macro set up to achieve these steps?

After editing my file path to "input" instead of "input.txt" error was resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a macro to open a file `E:\Test\Input.txt` to 1000 bytes, and save it as `E:\Test\TestMacro.txt`.

Notes:

- You can also change the default `To` bytes in the `File` page of the `Customize` dialog box, but this macro will change this only while opening the file, and revert it to default automatically when done.
- There is no macro method equivalent to `Save Opened Portion As`, but you can set bookmarks to all lines, extract bookmarked lines to a new file, and then save the new file as `TestMacro.txt`.

```
editor.WriteProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "DefaultBytesTo", 1000 );    // open to 1000 bytes
editor.RefreshCommonSettings();
editor.OpenFile( "E:\\Test\\Input.txt", 0, eeOpenDetectUnicode | eeOpenDetectUTF8 );
editor.WriteProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "DefaultBytesTo", 0 );       // open to unlimited
editor.RefreshCommonSettings();
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear All Bookmarks in This Document
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4588);  // Invert Bookmarks in This Document
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4590);  // Extract Bookmarked Lines in This Document to New File
document.Save( "E:\\Test\\TestMacro.txt" );
```

Comment: When I try executing this macro, it doesnt open file, so I reset Emeditor settings then received error that "The specified file does not exist' I think this has to do with the setting for set bookmarks to all lines, which I am trying to find?

Comment: Did you change the file path? Please be aware that a backslash ( \ ) must be escaped as double backslashes ( \\ ) in JavaScript.

Comment: I did not. I tried to duplicate exact files, so I could use the code exactly, then because my E: is external, I replicated with D:, I will edit in my question above. It did seem to show the large text editor opened without the file initially. But didnt save any ouput. If I click on Open as a new file, then it creates a 0Kb input and saves an output also 0kb

Comment: I think I figured out. Maybe because file in folder was input.txt but path was input.txt.txt. When I changed name to input, it seems to work, though with several warnings, that I can opt out of, so I am testing to see if this can work without triggering the same errors again.

Comment: Can I modify this Macro so that instead of "DefaultBytesTo" I can use something that will extract only x number of lines?

Comment: You can't specify the exact number of lines on the Large File Controller. However, you can open a file without the Large File Controller, and use the `SetActivePoint` method to specify the selection.

Comment: Is there a list of commands that I can view where it states for example, the code and then comments? ie editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear All Bookmarks, editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4588);  // Invert Bookmarks in This Document. I do see https://www.emeditor.org/en/cmd_index.html

Comment: `plugin.h` contains the list of IDs that you could use. https://github.com/Emurasoft/emeditor-plugin-library/blob/master/plugin.h